# How to use the results of a query in another query where i want to sum the results based on a criteria

Tags: mysql, sum

[DB schema diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au6JP.png)

[Full Code Here](http://github.com/SloCo-Albi/Supermarket-Project)

My problem is that I have constructed a query and I have it output its results in a table with these headings

```
Query code:
$Prices_query = "
SELECT p.Description pd
     , s.Description sd
     , b.Brand_Description
     , c.Price 
  FROM Products p
     , Supermarket s
     , Brand b
     , Prices c 
 WHERE " . $Product_query . " 
   AND " . $Supermarket_query . " 
   AND p.Product_ID = c.Product_ID
   AND s.Supermarket_ID = c.Supermarket_ID
   AND b.Brand_ID = p.Brand_ID
 ORDER 
    BY sd ";
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
Name | Supermarket | Brand | Price 
--- 
Milk | TESCO | Youmilk | 2.99

Bread | ASDA | Bakery | 4.99

Chocolate | TESCO | Lindt | 7.99
```

I would like to use the results from that query and sum the prices of all the products which are from the same supermarket.

WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACHIEVE

```
Supermarket | Price 
-
TESCO | 10.98

ASDA | 4.99
```

I have no clue how to do that. Any clues? thank you very much in advance

```
CURRENT OUTPUT
```

Is displaying the sample data above

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: pls, read StackOverflow notes on how to post a question

Comment: Forgot to add the code sorry

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
Also you can remove the php part. Because you only question is about the query, so focus on that.

Comment: What exactly is your doubt? If you want to sum those values you can use `SUM` with `GROUP BY`. If you want to also show the products you can do with a `UNION` or sum the values on the application. Please improve your answer with expected results and sample data at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems confusing. Following is the query that should solve your problem according to what I've understood.

Try the following query and comment below whether it's working or not.

**Edit**: Instead of doing `cross-join` and later filtering resultset with `AND` condition, I used `inner join` right away to remove complexity. Also I've removed unnecessary joins.

```
    $Prices_query = "
SELECT s.Description sd
       ,sum(c.Price) 
  FROM Prices c
        inner join Supermarket s
             on s.Supermarket_ID = c.Supermarket_ID
 WHERE " . $Product_query . "
   AND " . $Supermarket_query . " 
Group By sd
 ORDER 
    BY sd ";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The output of the query now is correct for the supermarkets' column as it shows them but unfortunately, nothing is shown in the prices column they are blank cells.

Comment: What does $product_query and $Supermarket_query contains?

Comment: The whole program, is supposed to let the user select products from a list with checkboxes. Then let the user select supermarkets from a list with checkboxes. And finally return a table with each supermarket and the sum of the products selected which are avaiable in the supermarket.

therefore $supermarket_query and $product_query are the selected products and supermarkets from the user.

if it sounds confusing I could share the whole code on GitHub to make things easier.

Comment: yes...please share the code. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing appears in the table. Maybe I'm missing something in the code other than the query. I'm not sure

Comment: There are 2 reasons for that. 1) I wrote table name Prices incorrectly(Sorry for that. I corrected it.). (2) The query won't show the sum of Price because the datatype of  Price is VARCHAR. You can't use sum() on column with varchar datatypes. In previous query results. It displays price because you are just retrieving the values. Solution: Change the datatype of Price if possible or you have to convert the values of price while calculating the sum. Think about it & tell me which way you want to solve the problem.

Comment: What datatype should i put?

Comment: You can go for decimal or float. For more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Tried decimal and nothing is displayed in the table not even the supermarkets unfortunatly....Using the first query you proposed the supermarkets appered but prices were blank. Now nothing displays

Comment: I've recreated scenario with relevant tables and their fields and the above query is working perfectly. You can check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/728b1/5/2     I think the problem is in your code specifically in your $Product_query or $Supermarket_query.

Comment: ok got it. It's not working because we've removed Product table from query but $Product_query still contains p.Product_ID which is not there anymore. Replace every "p." with "c." from each Product_ID and it'll work for sure,. Also i've added extra quotes in my last edit and it doesn't seem necessary. So i'll remove it.

Comment: So the table now displays The supermarket names but the prices coloumn is blank for some reason..... Here is the Prices_query echo SELECT s.Description sd ,sum(c.Price) FROM Prices c inner join Supermarket s on s.Supermarket_ID = c.Supermarket_ID WHERE (c.Product_ID = 1 OR c.Product_ID = 2 OR c.Product_ID = 3 OR c.Product_ID = 4 OR c.Product_ID = 5) AND (s.Supermarket_ID = 1 OR s.Supermarket_ID = 2 OR s.Supermarket_ID = 3 OR s.Supermarket_ID = 4 OR s.Supermarket_ID = 5) Group By sd ORDER BY sd

Comment: Ok this is frustrating. Can you execute this query directly on table? I mean pure mysql query.

Comment: If i input the query above in the databse it returns what i want which is good meaning the query is now functional

Comment: found the problem.... I was echoing only prices in the table and not "sum(c.Price)

Comment: I seriously love you. Thank you very much for your time. thanks, thanks thanks